# How do I interpret pstack logs?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

We had a production java process that froze today. We did some system checks like disk space checks, memory contentions etc. We guessed the process got deadlocked, so before we bounced the process, we ran the `pstack` command on the pid. I am unable to interpret much from the output. How do I read through these logs? I google searched pstack and related help but couldn't get much info..

This is the top of the stack trace. Looks like we are waiting on a condition? Is calling `DestroyVM` from JNI thread dangerous?

```
Thread 87 (Thread 0x406a3940 (LWP 18762)):

#0  0x000000325d60a899 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()  
#1  0x00002b6f8fd9177e in os::PlatformEvent::park ()  
#2  0x00002b6f8fd67595 in Monitor::IWait ()  
#3  0x00002b6f8fd67bfd in Monitor::wait ()  
#4  0x00002b6f8fea0295 in Threads::destroy_vm ()  
#5  0x00002b6f8fba6eab in jni_DestroyJavaVM ()  
#6  0x000000004000223f in JavaMain ()  
#7  0x000000325d606367 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0  
#8  0x000000325cad30ad in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Any pointers/help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Running a JMX Console didn't help. All we have are GC logs and the application logs (that froze abruptly as soon as the process froze. Everything in the app logs appeared normal, no exceptions or anything of the sort)

Comment: I think you need to post the whole dump. The one above is probably just a main method that has completed but has spawned other, non daemon, threads before completing hence it is sitting there waiting for everyone else to die before it dies.

Answer (score 1):

The stack you see here is from the `jvm` itself, and not your java process.
Don't forget that Java's JVM is a kind of virtualizer, the bytecode instructions of your program are interpreted and executed by the JVM, which is no more than a C (C++ certainly) program.

So I guess there are not no much information you can extract out of this stack, you should have connected a java debugger (`jdb` ?) to your JVM, if allowed, to get a meaningful backtrace.